# Naming variables in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

**Context**: I have a large table that I'm trying to assign to several variables. My columns are named things like "grp" or "scr". There are 48 rows, so to isolate each item, I want to be able to call the variables "grp1" or "scr5" or "grp48".

---

**getdata.php**

```
$m = 1;
while ($m<=48) {
    $conn->query("SELECT * matches WHERE mid = '$m'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $grp(1-48) = $row['grp']; // Not sure how to approach this.
    }
    $m++;
}
```

---

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong with using an array here?

Comment: I'm not opposed to other methods of handling this. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Use an array. If you don't know how to use an array, read a book on PHP.

Here's one: http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html

Also, don't run 48 queries where 1 will be more efficient.

```
$conn->query("SELECT * matches WHERE mid BETWEEN 1 AND 48 ORDER BY mid");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $grp[] = $row['grp']; // add each element to the end of the $grp array
}
```

After this is done, you'll have an array `$grp` with 48 entries. You can read each element individually:

```
echo $grp[24];
```

Comment: @JamesPatrick Beware that you'll have an index shift as php arrays start at `0` and you read your entries from `1`

Comment: @kingkero, good tip, that's covered in the chapter I linked to.